# Trying to show all driver names in a JSON Api with codable protocol in swift 4

Tags: swift4, codable

I am working with an F1 API and want to show all driver names in a swift project.  I am using the codable protocol and I understand how I would access one name or property from the JSON API. It is just if I wanted to access all a selected properties from that JSON API. I have tried countless different ways to achieve this but with little success.  Below is the code I have.

```
struct MRData: Codable {
let xmlns: String
let series: String
let url: String
let limit, offset, total: String
let standingsTable: StandingsTable

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case xmlns, series, url, limit, offset, total
    case standingsTable = "StandingsTable"
  }
}

struct StandingsTable: Codable {
let season: String
let standingsLists: [StandingsList]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case season
    case standingsLists = "StandingsLists"
 }
}

struct StandingsList: Codable {
let season, round: String
let driverStandings: [DriverStanding]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case season, round
    case driverStandings = "DriverStandings"
  }
 }

struct DriverStanding: Codable {
let position, positionText, points, wins: String
let driver: Driver
let constructors: [Constructor]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case position, positionText, points, wins
    case driver = "Driver"
    case constructors = "Constructors"
  }
}

struct Constructor: Codable {
let constructorId: String
let url: String
let name: String
let nationality: String
}

struct Driver: Codable {
let driverId: String
let url: String
let givenName, familyName, dateOfBirth, nationality: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonUrlString = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/1981/driverstandings.json"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let f1Data = try JSONDecoder().decode(F1Data.self, from: data)

              let season = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.season

   print(f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].
   driverStandings[1].driver.familyName)
          print(season)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }.resume()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a for loop.

```
let firstDriver = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
            for driver in firstDriver {
            //print(firstDriver)
                print(driver.driver.familyName)
            }
```